# Google Dev Tools

Tags: css, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

I was wondering why Google Dev tools is loading the wrong CSS script when working on responsive design

```
@media screen and (max-width:375px) {
...
    #name{
      font-size: calc(.8rem + .1vw);
    }
...
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
...
  #name{
      font-size: calc(1rem + .1vw);
    }
...
}
```

When running the google dev tools it runs the second query rather:

[image]

Comment: The second query is valid for your example, it matches when the width is less than 480px. Try adding `min-width` to the query or changing the order?

Comment: use `480px` in the first position and then `375px` and so on... (greater to lesser screen size)

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you that worked! i switched the query size and placed a `max-width:374px;` followed by a `min-width: 375px;`

Comment: @AmanSharma I learned in a bootcamp to go lesser to greater. Could you provide some docs that say otherwise

Comment: @Carlitos may be there is lot of docs in internet, but i am experienced with many years in css. I gave you advice that what i faced in my journey and i have so many solution to do it.